# errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection", "errorMessage": "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND in Node.js

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework

I am getting below error in Cloudwatch for get API.

```
ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
    "errorMessage": "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND portal-dev.test.com",
    "reason": {
        "errorType": "Error",
        "errorMessage": "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND portal-dev.test.com",
        "code": "ENOTFOUND",
        "errno": "ENOTFOUND",
        "syscall": "getaddrinfo",
        "hostname": "portal-dev.test.com",
        "stack": [
            "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND portal-dev.test.com",
            "    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26)"
        ]
    },
    "promise": {},
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND portal-dev.test.com",
        "    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)",
        "    at process.emit (events.js:314:20)",
        "    at process.emit (/var/task/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:495:21)",
        "    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"
    ]
}
```

how can we fix this error?
When I hit the API in postman I am getting 502 Internal Server Error.

Comment: It looks like the logic inside your function is trying to make a HTTP request to an URL that is not available. Are you sure you want to call "portal-dev.test.com" inside your function?

Comment: Past the api code you are hitting